# ASP.NET Session Expires Whenever the markup is changed

Tags: asp.net, session, visual-studio-2012

I am having strange problem while testing my application. Every time i make change in .aspx page "means change any html", and when i refresh the page it takes me to the login page.

Thus the Session is expiring every time i make change in .aspx page.

I was not experiencing this problem before.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with TFS

Any Suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing .aspx does not mean changing html. If you using and changing server controls you have to rebuild app every time before lunch.

If you don't want Session to drop after recompile you can use StateServer(ASP.NET session state service)

You can check more here: [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)